# How to add profiles(view) of the same analytics account in the Analytics API?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I started setting up the HelloAnalyticsApi, and I finally have it "working". But it only shows one view of one of the websites I own. Is there a way I can add 3 or 4 more views to the HelloAnalyticsApi so it will show all my websites and data instead of just one website with one ga:sessions data?

This is the code that HelloAnalyticsApi prints

```
function printResults(&$results) {
if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {
$profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();
$rows = $results->getRows();
$sessions = $rows[0][0];

print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";


} else {
print '<p>No results found.</p>';
}
}
```

On the website it shows:

First view (profile) found: www.website1.nl[view1]

Total sessions: 2394

But I would like it to show:

Website 1: 2394 Sessions

Website 2: 1999 Sessions

and so on

Help would be very much appreciated, because I been stuck on this for some time now.

I can provide more information if needed, but I basicly just need to know how to add more views to this code, and why it only shows for one website.

thanks

Comment: you can only request one view at a time from the api your going to have to put it in a loop.  try and figure out where its setting the profile ID.

Comment: @DalmTo
I can't seem to figure out where its setting the profile ID, I have followed the Hello Analytics tutorial for PhP and I think that the profile ID is being stored in $profileId with the function getFirstprofileId.. What would I have to loop in order to achieve the other profiles(views)?
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hello analytics php on Googles website is out of date. use http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/ or http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/